# How to move an Azure resource from one region to another region

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I have created one Azure Function App in an existing Azure Resource Group. While creating a Function App, by mistake I didn't notice the selected region, and it got created in "South Central US" region. After a significant development, I realized this mistake, and now want to move it to "West Europe" region, so it gets aligned with rest of my resources.

Any idea of how I can move a resource from one region to other region, without deleting and recreating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is still no way to change your deployment from one region to the other. You'll have to create another Azure Function in that correct region and redeploy your application.

Troy Hunt outlines his journey with an Azure Website [here](https://www.troyhunt.com/i-put-my-azure-website-in-wrong/) but the same steps still apply.

Comment: Nice post, and thanks for sharing. Yes, just like many visitors commented on that blog, it is now high time Azure provide this as an in-built functionality!

Answer (score 0):

still, I don't see any new option (We can move resources from one resource group/ subscription level).

I think as of now 3 options available

1. Create a resource in the new region then delete existing resource.
2. Deploy new resource with the same configuration using PowerShell/CLI.

[image]

3. Deploy through portal (Export Template > Deploy > Select New region > change parameters then Purchase) similar to option 2, but you don't need to write any script.

Ultimately all three options would create a new resource and you need to update access key in the dependent services. I think option 2 is a good choice for a production workload.